# Is there any production-ready chat app for Django?

Tags: django, chat

I'd like to add a chat app into my Django site but I got perplexed with number of [packages] and diverse array of technologies used. So I am wondering what is the best approach/package to be used in production?

I am open to all solutions from native Django apps to easily integrated additions from Tornado, Twisted, js based, etc.

Comment: See https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/chat/

Comment: If legacy browser support is not an issue the new WebRTC-based chats are they way to go http://webrtc.org/ or usually older chats are XMPP-based, see https://conversejs.org/

Comment: @AlexMartelli I've already seen that package list but can not decide which one to choose, specially because they are so diverse and none seems to stand out of the crowd.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa can you please refer me to some Django-specific implementation of WebRTC?